# Does this language still exist or is it extinct?

Tags: self-learning, identification

I found (and bought) a book called "A descriptive phonology of Thaqovelith" but when I search thaqovelith on the internet, I find nothing except the reference to that book. It was published in 1980 so I believe that it wasn't extinct then. Does anyone have any information on this? It says it's an African language.

Comment: I assume you are referring to Gregory Paul Shaltz Jr's PhD dissertation? I searched Springer, ResearchGate, Academia.edu, JStor and ERIC and found no other mentions except for that dissertation. I also couldn't find out where Gregory Paul Shaltz can still be reached.

Comment: Yes I am. It has an ISBN number written in the book, but when I search it up, it comes up empty. No book. (Same thing with my book on Korfball :P )

Comment: It is available in a few [university libraries](http://www.worldcat.org/title/descriptive-phonology-of-thaqovelith/oclc/8315762&referer=brief_results), so I can get it if I want to. But what we need is more recent information, since the language could have disappeared at some point in the last 36 years.

Comment: All I really want to know is if it actually still exists or not. It's an unusual book to have though :)

Comment: Welcome to Language Learning! It seems like you're trying to determine whether this language is extinct or not; however, this isn't directly related to the topic of language learning, as nowhere in your question do you state that you are looking to learn this language. Therefore, I think this question might be better received on Linguistics.SE. I've voted to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: @fi12 Sorry, I did not realize there was a linguistics stack exchange

Comment: @Qiangong2 no problem :)

Comment: Although the question is on hold, I'd like to add that I could not find the language in *Compendium of the World's Languages* (2 vols., ed. G. L. Campbell, 1991) or in *Die Sprachfamilien der Welt* (2 vols., ed. Ernst Klausen, 2013).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Could the language be known as Thaqovelith to the locals and something else to everyone else?

Comment: That is not unusual and definitely possible. Does Shaltz' dissertation say where the language is spoken or which language family it belongs to?

Comment: I'm away at the moment, but I think it says Northeastern algeria

Comment: That makes sense. According to [TermSciences](http://inserm.termsciences.fr/-/Index/Rechercher/Rapide/Naviguer/Arbre/?idt=TE.152421&lng=en&aTree=selectionner), Thaqovelith is a [Berber language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berber_languages) (or dialect?). Some other Berger languages also have names ending on -it: Tashelhit, Taqbaylit, Tamaziɣt, etc.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I reposted this here: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/19322/is-this-language-extinct where the question is more relevant